# How to find local maximum in a Numpy array and then trace local minimum around it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

If I have a numpy array like this:

```
 np.array([[5, 5, 5, 3,  5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4],
          [4, 4, 4, 5,  5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5],
          [3, 3, 6, 5,  5, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6],
          [4, 4, 1, 5,  4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5],
          [4, 5, 4, 2,  4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5],
          [5, 5, 7, 7,  3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4],
          [5, 5, 6, 8,  7, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5],
          [0, 0, 5, 7, 10, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5],
          [0, 0, 5, 6,  6, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

How do I find the maximum value 10? and then the closest local minimum upwards from it which is 3?

Once I find the local minimum I need to find the local minimums surrounding that point and trace them such that I get:

```
 np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: What's your definition of "local" and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Additionally, when you say 'surrounding', why does that not also include the zero rows near the bottom? Those touch the bottom-right `3`. Do clarify!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ambiguities you'd need to deal with. It sounds like the algorithm you want does the following:

1. Find the maximum A. This can be done with built-ins, but note that there can be more than one. How do you pick?
2. For each element B, enumerate its direct neighbors. Does that include diagonal neighbors?
3. Check if all neighbors of B are larger than B, making B a local minimum.
4. If B is a local minimum, calculate its distance from A. What is the distance function?
5. Return the minimum with the smallest distance from A

(Note that there may be several local minima that are equally distant from the maximum, and which is returned depends on how the array is traversed.)